# Query multiple records in rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've looked around but can't seem to find anything like this for querying via an API (this is the backend to an iOS app) Basically, what I want to be able to do is make a route like this:

```
localhost:3000/api/products/52,53,67,78,etc...
```

And this query would return the products with ids 52, 53, 67, 78 and which ever other ids are listed. Currently I have a regular route like:

```
localhost:3000/api/products/52
```

and this correctly retrieves the product with an API of 52. My routes currently look like this:

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do 
scope module: :v1 do
  resources :products, only: [:index, :show, :destroy, :create] do 
    resources :reviews, only: [:index]
  end
  get '/search/products', to: "products#search"
  resources :categories, only: [:index, :show]
  resources :charges, only: [:create]
  resources :customers, only: [:create]
  resources :users, only: [:create, :show]
  resources :accounts, only: [:create]
  post '/login', to: "sessions#create"

 end
end
```

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just send the `ids` as array in params?

The http query with params(or send it as `x-www-form-urlencoded` recommened):

```
localhost:3000/api/products?ids[]=52&ids[]=53&ids[]=67...
```

And in the action for exmple:

```
  def index
    products = Product.where('id IN (?)', params[:ids])
    if products.any?
      render json: { success: true, products: products }
    else
      render json: { success: false, products: products }
    end
  end
```

Comment: I am encoding all requests as JSON, and would prefer not to mess with the Router I've set up in the iOS app to fix it to make exceptions only for certain requests, and using JSON I can't send params in a GET request

Answer (score 2):

As others have suggested, you should pass the params as an array:

http://localhost:3000/api/products?ids[]=52&ids[]=53&ids[]=67

However, your controller code could be even shorter than what the others answers suggested:

```
def index
  products = Product.where(id: params[:ids])
  render json: { success: products.any?, products: products }
end
```